# Extend list changing the product behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, extends

I have several list that are multiplied between them and with external variables, for example:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [2, 1, 2, 1]
var_1 = 2
var_2 = 3
```

I need to multiply list values one by one expecting the following result:

```
result = list_1 * list_2 * var_1 * var_4  
#  Result = [12,  12, 36, 24]
```

I know this can be made with a list comprehension, for example:

```
result = [var_1 * var_2 * a * b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

The problem with list comprehension is that somethings **var_1** and **var_2** are lists, and they need to be in the **zip** arguments. Another problem is that the number of lists is large and the code looks ugly.

Another solution is numpy arrays, but I want to do this with classic python lists.

What I want is extend the python list, and override some method to change the product behavior, it is posible?